# That's why vs. Is that why

Tags: difference, idiomatic-language

Two people in a bar.

Woman: I got a B on my final exam.

Man: **That's why you're here?** / **Is that why you're here?**

Are these equally idiomatic? What's the difference between them?

Comment: "Is that why you're here?" sounds more natural to me but both are grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

'Is that why you're here?' is a question.

'That's why you're here?' is a question expressed as a statement. When written, the final question mark identifies it as a question, and when spoken, there would be a rising intonation.

Both are correct, and both mean the same thing.

[Statement questions (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-statement-questions-you-re-over-18)